# Javascript implementation of Murmurhash3 to give the same result as Murmurhash3.cpp used by transform available in Python's sklearn

Tags: javascript, python, c++, scikit-learn, murmurhash

(I am VERY sorry I am not allowed to add many URLs to help me better explain my problems in this post because I am new on StackOverflow and my StackOverflow account has very low privilege).

**Summary**

Can anyone please guide me on how to modify `murmurhash3.js` (below) so that it produces the same hash as `MurmurHash3.cpp` (below) does? I provide a simple python code "simple_python_wrapper.py" for MurmurHash3.cpp based on what I need. The simple_python_wrapper.py should work on your computer if you have sklearn installed.

I have heavily used `Murmurhash3.cpp` (shown below) while using `transform` from sklearn (a Python Machine Learning Library): `from sklearn.feature_extraction._hashing import transform` in one of my machine learning projects. `transform` uses `Murmurhash3.cpp` deep down in sklearn's  implementation/import tree.

**More details**

***hash % (2^18) {that is "hash modulus 2^18"} based on MurmurHash3.cpp***

```
"hello" gives 260679
"there" gives 45525
```

***hash % (2^18) {that is "hash modulus 2^18"} based on murmurhash3.js***

```
"hello" gives -58999
"there" gives 65775
```

***murmurhash3.js***

```
/*
 *  The MurmurHash3 algorithm was created by Austin Appleby.  This JavaScript port was authored
 *  by whitequark (based on Java port by Yonik Seeley) and is placed into the public domain.
 *  The author hereby disclaims copyright to this source code.
 *
 *  This produces exactly the same hash values as the final C++ version of MurmurHash3 and
 *  is thus suitable for producing the same hash values across platforms.
 *
 *  There are two versions of this hash implementation. First interprets the string as a
 *  sequence of bytes, ignoring most significant byte of each codepoint. The second one
 *  interprets the string as a UTF-16 codepoint sequence, and appends each 16-bit codepoint
 *  to the hash independently. The latter mode was not written to be compatible with
 *  any other implementation, but it should offer better performance for JavaScript-only
 *  applications.
 *
 *  See http://github.com/whitequark/murmurhash3-js for future updates to this file.
 */

var MurmurHash3 = {
    mul32: function(m, n) {
        var nlo = n & 0xffff;
        var nhi = n - nlo;
        return ((nhi * m | 0) + (nlo * m | 0)) | 0;
    },

    hashBytes: function(data, len, seed) {
        var c1 = 0xcc9e2d51, c2 = 0x1b873593;

        var h1 = seed;
        var roundedEnd = len & ~0x3;

        for (var i = 0; i < roundedEnd; i += 4) {
            var k1 = (data.charCodeAt(i)     & 0xff)        |
                ((data.charCodeAt(i + 1) & 0xff) << 8)  |
                ((data.charCodeAt(i + 2) & 0xff) << 16) |
                ((data.charCodeAt(i + 3) & 0xff) << 24);

            k1 = this.mul32(k1, c1);
            k1 = ((k1 & 0x1ffff) << 15) | (k1 >>> 17);  // ROTL32(k1,15);
            k1 = this.mul32(k1, c2);

            h1 ^= k1;
            h1 = ((h1 & 0x7ffff) << 13) | (h1 >>> 19);  // ROTL32(h1,13);
            h1 = (h1 * 5 + 0xe6546b64) | 0;
        }

        k1 = 0;

        switch(len % 4) {
            case 3:
                k1 = (data.charCodeAt(roundedEnd + 2) & 0xff) << 16;
                // fallthrough
            case 2:
                k1 |= (data.charCodeAt(roundedEnd + 1) & 0xff) << 8;
                // fallthrough
            case 1:
                k1 |= (data.charCodeAt(roundedEnd) & 0xff);
                k1 = this.mul32(k1, c1);
                k1 = ((k1 & 0x1ffff) << 15) | (k1 >>> 17);  // ROTL32(k1,15);
                k1 = this.mul32(k1, c2);
                h1 ^= k1;
        }

        // finalization
        h1 ^= len;

        // fmix(h1);
        h1 ^= h1 >>> 16;
        h1  = this.mul32(h1, 0x85ebca6b);
        h1 ^= h1 >>> 13;
        h1  = this.mul32(h1, 0xc2b2ae35);
        h1 ^= h1 >>> 16;

        return h1;
    },

    hashString: function(data, len, seed) {
        var c1 = 0xcc9e2d51, c2 = 0x1b873593;

        var h1 = seed;
        var roundedEnd = len & ~0x1;

        for (var i = 0; i < roundedEnd; i += 2) {
            var k1 = data.charCodeAt(i) | (data.charCodeAt(i + 1) << 16);

            k1 = this.mul32(k1, c1);
            k1 = ((k1 & 0x1ffff) << 15) | (k1 >>> 17);  // ROTL32(k1,15);
            k1 = this.mul32(k1, c2);

            h1 ^= k1;
            h1 = ((h1 & 0x7ffff) << 13) | (h1 >>> 19);  // ROTL32(h1,13);
            h1 = (h1 * 5 + 0xe6546b64) | 0;
        }

        if((len % 2) == 1) {
            k1 = data.charCodeAt(roundedEnd);
            k1 = this.mul32(k1, c1);
            k1 = ((k1 & 0x1ffff) << 15) | (k1 >>> 17);  // ROTL32(k1,15);
            k1 = this.mul32(k1, c2);
            h1 ^= k1;
        }

        // finalization
        h1 ^= (len << 1);

        // fmix(h1);
        h1 ^= h1 >>> 16;
        h1  = this.mul32(h1, 0x85ebca6b);
        h1 ^= h1 >>> 13;
        h1  = this.mul32(h1, 0xc2b2ae35);
        h1 ^= h1 >>> 16;

        return h1;
    }
};

if(typeof module !== "undefined" && typeof module.exports !== "undefined") {
    module.exports = MurmurHash3;
}
```

***Here is the HTML code + Javascript I am using to test the javascript***

https://jsbin.com/gicomikike/edit?html,js,output

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="murmurhash3.js"></script>

<script>

function call_murmurhash3_32_gc () {
    var key = $('textarea#textarea1').val();
    var seed = 0;
    var hash = MurmurHash3.hashString (key, key.length, seed);
    $('div#div1').text(hash);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
Body

<form>

    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id=textarea1></textarea>

    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Hash" onclick="call_murmurhash3_32_gc()"/>

</form>


<div id=div1>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

***simple_python_wrapper.py***

This makes use of MurmurHash3.cpp in sklearn's import tree.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction._hashing import transform 
import numpy as np

def getHashIndex (words):

    raw_X = words
    n_features = 262144 # 2 ** 18
    dtype = np.float32 #np.float64

    #transform(raw_X, Py_ssize_t n_features, dtype)
    indices_a, indptr, values = transform (raw_X, n_features, dtype)

    return indices_a 


words = [[("hello", 1), ("there", 1)]] 

print getHashIndex (words)
```

Output

```
[260679  45525]
```

***MurmurHash3.cpp***

```
I copied this code is available here 
https://github.com/karanlyons/murmurHash3.js/blob/master/murmurHash3.js
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MurmurHash3 was written by Austin Appleby, and is placed in the public
// domain. The author hereby disclaims copyright to this source code.

// Note - The x86 and x64 versions do _not_ produce the same results, as the
// algorithms are optimized for their respective platforms. You can still
// compile and run any of them on any platform, but your performance with the
// non-native version will be less than optimal.

#include "MurmurHash3.h"

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Platform-specific functions and macros

// Microsoft Visual Studio

#if defined(_MSC_VER)

#define FORCE_INLINE    __forceinline

#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROTL32(x,y) _rotl(x,y)
#define ROTL64(x,y) _rotl64(x,y)

#define BIG_CONSTANT(x) (x)

// Other compilers

#else   // defined(_MSC_VER)

#if defined(GNUC) && ((GNUC > 4) || (GNUC == 4 && GNUC_MINOR >= 4))

/* gcc version >= 4.4 4.1 = RHEL 5, 4.4 = RHEL 6.
 * Don't inline for RHEL 5 gcc which is 4.1 */
#define FORCE_INLINE attribute((always_inline))

#else

#define FORCE_INLINE

#endif


inline uint32_t rotl32 ( uint32_t x, int8_t r )
{
  return (x << r) | (x >> (32 - r));
}

inline uint64_t rotl64 ( uint64_t x, int8_t r )
{
  return (x << r) | (x >> (64 - r));
}

#define ROTL32(x,y) rotl32(x,y)
#define ROTL64(x,y) rotl64(x,y)

#define BIG_CONSTANT(x) (x##LLU)

#endif // !defined(_MSC_VER)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Block read - if your platform needs to do endian-swapping or can only
// handle aligned reads, do the conversion here

FORCE_INLINE uint32_t getblock ( const uint32_t * p, int i )
{
  return p[i];
}

FORCE_INLINE uint64_t getblock ( const uint64_t * p, int i )
{
  return p[i];
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Finalization mix - force all bits of a hash block to avalanche

FORCE_INLINE uint32_t fmix ( uint32_t h )
{
  h ^= h >> 16;
  h *= 0x85ebca6b;
  h ^= h >> 13;
  h *= 0xc2b2ae35;
  h ^= h >> 16;

  return h;
}

//----------

FORCE_INLINE uint64_t fmix ( uint64_t k )
{
  k ^= k >> 33;
  k *= BIG_CONSTANT(0xff51afd7ed558ccd);
  k ^= k >> 33;
  k *= BIG_CONSTANT(0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53);
  k ^= k >> 33;

  return k;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void MurmurHash3_x86_32 ( const void * key, int len,
                          uint32_t seed, void * out )
{
  const uint8_t * data = (const uint8_t*)key;
  const int nblocks = len / 4;

  uint32_t h1 = seed;

  uint32_t c1 = 0xcc9e2d51;
  uint32_t c2 = 0x1b873593;

  //----------
  // body

  const uint32_t * blocks = (const uint32_t *)(data + nblocks*4);

  for(int i = -nblocks; i; i++)
  {
    uint32_t k1 = getblock(blocks,i);

    k1 *= c1;
    k1 = ROTL32(k1,15);
    k1 *= c2;

    h1 ^= k1;
    h1 = ROTL32(h1,13);
    h1 = h1*5+0xe6546b64;
  }

  //----------
  // tail

  const uint8_t * tail = (const uint8_t*)(data + nblocks*4);

  uint32_t k1 = 0;

  switch(len & 3)
  {
  case 3: k1 ^= tail[2] << 16;
  case 2: k1 ^= tail[1] << 8;
  case 1: k1 ^= tail[0];
          k1 *= c1; k1 = ROTL32(k1,15); k1 *= c2; h1 ^= k1;
  };

  //----------
  // finalization

  h1 ^= len;

  h1 = fmix(h1);

  *(uint32_t*)out = h1;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void MurmurHash3_x86_128 ( const void * key, const int len,
                           uint32_t seed, void * out )
{
  const uint8_t * data = (const uint8_t*)key;
  const int nblocks = len / 16;

  uint32_t h1 = seed;
  uint32_t h2 = seed;
  uint32_t h3 = seed;
  uint32_t h4 = seed;

  uint32_t c1 = 0x239b961b;
  uint32_t c2 = 0xab0e9789;
  uint32_t c3 = 0x38b34ae5;
  uint32_t c4 = 0xa1e38b93;

  //----------
  // body

  const uint32_t * blocks = (const uint32_t *)(data + nblocks*16);

  for(int i = -nblocks; i; i++)
  {
    uint32_t k1 = getblock(blocks,i*4+0);
    uint32_t k2 = getblock(blocks,i*4+1);
    uint32_t k3 = getblock(blocks,i*4+2);
    uint32_t k4 = getblock(blocks,i*4+3);

    k1 *= c1; k1  = ROTL32(k1,15); k1 *= c2; h1 ^= k1;

    h1 = ROTL32(h1,19); h1 += h2; h1 = h1*5+0x561ccd1b;

    k2 *= c2; k2  = ROTL32(k2,16); k2 *= c3; h2 ^= k2;

    h2 = ROTL32(h2,17); h2 += h3; h2 = h2*5+0x0bcaa747;

    k3 *= c3; k3  = ROTL32(k3,17); k3 *= c4; h3 ^= k3;

    h3 = ROTL32(h3,15); h3 += h4; h3 = h3*5+0x96cd1c35;

    k4 *= c4; k4  = ROTL32(k4,18); k4 *= c1; h4 ^= k4;

    h4 = ROTL32(h4,13); h4 += h1; h4 = h4*5+0x32ac3b17;
  }

  //----------
  // tail

  const uint8_t * tail = (const uint8_t*)(data + nblocks*16);

  uint32_t k1 = 0;
  uint32_t k2 = 0;
  uint32_t k3 = 0;
  uint32_t k4 = 0;

  switch(len & 15)
  {
  case 15: k4 ^= tail[14] << 16;
  case 14: k4 ^= tail[13] << 8;
  case 13: k4 ^= tail[12] << 0;
           k4 *= c4; k4  = ROTL32(k4,18); k4 *= c1; h4 ^= k4;

  case 12: k3 ^= tail[11] << 24;
  case 11: k3 ^= tail[10] << 16;
  case 10: k3 ^= tail[ 9] << 8;
  case  9: k3 ^= tail[ 8] << 0;
           k3 *= c3; k3  = ROTL32(k3,17); k3 *= c4; h3 ^= k3;

  case  8: k2 ^= tail[ 7] << 24;
  case  7: k2 ^= tail[ 6] << 16;
  case  6: k2 ^= tail[ 5] << 8;
  case  5: k2 ^= tail[ 4] << 0;
           k2 *= c2; k2  = ROTL32(k2,16); k2 *= c3; h2 ^= k2;

  case  4: k1 ^= tail[ 3] << 24;
  case  3: k1 ^= tail[ 2] << 16;
  case  2: k1 ^= tail[ 1] << 8;
  case  1: k1 ^= tail[ 0] << 0;
           k1 *= c1; k1  = ROTL32(k1,15); k1 *= c2; h1 ^= k1;
  };

  //----------
  // finalization

  h1 ^= len; h2 ^= len; h3 ^= len; h4 ^= len;

  h1 += h2; h1 += h3; h1 += h4;
  h2 += h1; h3 += h1; h4 += h1;

  h1 = fmix(h1);
  h2 = fmix(h2);
  h3 = fmix(h3);
  h4 = fmix(h4);

  h1 += h2; h1 += h3; h1 += h4;
  h2 += h1; h3 += h1; h4 += h1;

  ((uint32_t*)out)[0] = h1;
  ((uint32_t*)out)[1] = h2;
  ((uint32_t*)out)[2] = h3;
  ((uint32_t*)out)[3] = h4;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void MurmurHash3_x64_128 ( const void * key, const int len,
                           const uint32_t seed, void * out )
{
  const uint8_t * data = (const uint8_t*)key;
  const int nblocks = len / 16;

  uint64_t h1 = seed;
  uint64_t h2 = seed;

  uint64_t c1 = BIG_CONSTANT(0x87c37b91114253d5);
  uint64_t c2 = BIG_CONSTANT(0x4cf5ad432745937f);

  //----------
  // body

  const uint64_t * blocks = (const uint64_t *)(data);

  for(int i = 0; i < nblocks; i++)
  {
    uint64_t k1 = getblock(blocks,i*2+0);
    uint64_t k2 = getblock(blocks,i*2+1);

    k1 *= c1; k1  = ROTL64(k1,31); k1 *= c2; h1 ^= k1;

    h1 = ROTL64(h1,27); h1 += h2; h1 = h1*5+0x52dce729;

    k2 *= c2; k2  = ROTL64(k2,33); k2 *= c1; h2 ^= k2;

    h2 = ROTL64(h2,31); h2 += h1; h2 = h2*5+0x38495ab5;
  }

  //----------
  // tail

  const uint8_t * tail = (const uint8_t*)(data + nblocks*16);

  uint64_t k1 = 0;
  uint64_t k2 = 0;

  switch(len & 15)
  {
  case 15: k2 ^= uint64_t(tail[14]) << 48;
  case 14: k2 ^= uint64_t(tail[13]) << 40;
  case 13: k2 ^= uint64_t(tail[12]) << 32;
  case 12: k2 ^= uint64_t(tail[11]) << 24;
  case 11: k2 ^= uint64_t(tail[10]) << 16;
  case 10: k2 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 9]) << 8;
  case  9: k2 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 8]) << 0;
           k2 *= c2; k2  = ROTL64(k2,33); k2 *= c1; h2 ^= k2;

  case  8: k1 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 7]) << 56;
  case  7: k1 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 6]) << 48;
  case  6: k1 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 5]) << 40;
  case  5: k1 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 4]) << 32;
  case  4: k1 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 3]) << 24;
  case  3: k1 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 2]) << 16;
  case  2: k1 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 1]) << 8;
  case  1: k1 ^= uint64_t(tail[ 0]) << 0;
           k1 *= c1; k1  = ROTL64(k1,31); k1 *= c2; h1 ^= k1;
  };

  //----------
  // finalization

  h1 ^= len; h2 ^= len;

  h1 += h2;
  h2 += h1;

  h1 = fmix(h1);
  h2 = fmix(h2);

  h1 += h2;
  h2 += h1;

  ((uint64_t*)out)[0] = h1;
  ((uint64_t*)out)[1] = h2;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Let me explain that a bit more.

`from sklearn.feature_extraction._hashing import transform` 
makes use of this code `https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/412996f09b6756752dfd3736c306d46fca8f1aa1/sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.pyx`
which makes use of this
`from sklearn.utils.murmurhash cimport murmurhash3_bytes_s32` 
which in turn makes use of this
`https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/murmurhash.pyx` 
which is built on this
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/src/MurmurHash3.cpp . **So, MurmurHash3.cpp is very important. I need a Javascript version of this exact MurmurHash3.cpp such that the Javascript code and MurmurHash3.cpp would produce the same result**.

I need this because I want to make some of my machine learning tools available online and the hashing needs to be done on the client's web browser.

So far, I have found a few Javascript implementations of MurmurHash3. However, murmurhash3.js `https://github.com/whitequark/murmurhash3-js/blob/master/murmurhash3.js` seems to be closest (in terms of codes structure) to the MurmurHash3.cpp used by sklearn. But I still d not get the same hash from both of them.

Can anyone please guide me on how to modify `murmurhash3.js` (above) so that it produces the same hash as `MurmurHash3.cpp` (above) does?

Comment: Superficially, the C++ `MurmurHash3_x86_32` function resembles the JavaScript `hashBytes` function, but your test harness is calling the JavaScript `hashString` function, which processes data in 16-bit chunks, rather than 32-bit chunks.  So I suggest you see if `hashBytes` works.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles you have SAVED me today! You are right on point. With your suggestion and a little tweak, my problems are solved. I will give a bit more details bellow as an answer to the question. THANKS a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on suggestions from @ChristopherOicles, I changed my `Javascript` code (my the header off my HTML code) to use `hashBytes` instead of `hashString` as shown below. I also noticed that I needed to change the returned value of `hashBytes` to its absolute value for my purpose (so I did). These solve my problems and now I get the same hash from the Python/C++ codes and from the Javascript codes.

**Modified Javascript Function in my HTML file**

```
<script>
function call_murmurhash3_32_gc () {
    var key = $('textarea#textarea1').val();
    var seed = 0;
    var hash = MurmurHash3.hashBytes (key, key.length, seed);
    $('div#div1').text(Math.abs (hash) % 262144);
    }
</script>
```

My complete solution is here https://jsbin.com/qilokot/edit?html,js,output
.

Again, many thanks to `Christopher Oicles` and to everyone who tried to help me in some ways.

Answer (score 1):

*I’m late to the party, but I only hit this problem now.*

If the string is not made up of regular ASCII characters, the implementation you are using will yield different results from the reference implementation. This is because it [uses `charCodeAt` and a byte mask](https://github.com/whitequark/murmurhash3-js/blob/master/murmurhash3.js#L33-L36) to get the bytes that need to be hashed from the input string. If the string contains any other characters, the results will diverge unless you are doing the exact same thing to decode the string on your other platforms.

I made [a fork of MurmurHash3js](https://github.com/pid/murmurHash3js) that uses bytes as input instead of strings. Here's how you use it:

```
npm install murmurhash3js-revisited
```

Then in your js files you can do:

```
import MurmurHash3 from 'murmurhash3js-revisited';

const str = "My hovercraft is full of eels.";
// get utf-8 bytes
const bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(str);

MurmurHash3.x86.hash32(bytes);
// output: 2953494853

MurmurHash3.x86.hash128(bytes);
// output: "e3a186aee169ba6c6a8bd9343c68fa9c"

MurmurHash3.x64.hash128(bytes);
// output: "03e5e14d358c16d1e5ae86df7ed5cfcb"

MurmurHash3.x86.hash32("any string");
// output: undefined
// (x86.hash128 and x64.hash128 also return undefined)
```

You can read about performance considerations and try out an interactive comparison between different JavaScript implementations in [my library's documentation](https://cimi.io/murmurhash3js-revisited/).